# Finding the value of $m-n$ if $m+n=7$, $mn=12$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Finding the value of $m-n$ if $m+n=7$, $mn=12$

I tried the following,

As we know, $a^2+b^2=(a-b)^2+2ab$

But, where do I put $m+n$ value?

Please help. I am stuck.

Comment: $$(m-n)^2 = (m+n)^2 - 4mn$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use
$$(m-n)^2=(m+n)^2-4mn=7^2-4\cdot 12=1.$$
So?

Comment: What about $-1$

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: Note that what I wrote is $(m-n)^2=1$, not $m-n=1$.

Comment: Oh I missed the squared part.

Answer (score 10):

**Hint**: Since $m+n = 7$, we have $m = 7-n$. Hence, $12 = mn = (7-n)n$.

Can you solve this quadratic?

Answer (score 4):

Go one step further with what you are trying to use:
$$(a+b)^2 = (a-b)^2 + 4ab$$

Answer (score 2):

$(m+n)^2-(m-n)^2=4mn$

$7^2-(m-n)^2=4*12$

$49-48=(m-n)^2$

yields

$m-n=+-(1)$

Comment: mn = 12, not 14